# JS style static property for Rust struct

Tags: rust

In javascript we can use the `static` keyword to define a static method or property for a class. Neither static methods nor static properties can be called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on the class itself. So, for instance, we could count the number of instances of a certain class we've created:

```js
class Player{
    static playerCount = 0;

    constructor(){
        Player.playerCount ++;
    }

}
```

Is their anything in rust that would roughly equivalent to this? Or possibly a library/macro that allows for something similar?

```rust
struct Player{}
impl Player{
    static playerCount;
    pub fn new()->Self{
        playerCount ++
        //increment playerCount 
    }
}
```

Comment: Rust does not support static fields in structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such a thing as a static field in a Rust `struct`. Rust's `struct`s are closer to their C namesake than the classes you'd find in object-oriented languages.

The rough equivalent is probably a [`static mut` variable,](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.static.html#mutable-statics) which requires the use of `unsafe` code. This is because a globally accessible, mutable value is going to be a source of undefined behavior (such as data races) and Rust wants all code to be free of UB unless you write the word `unsafe`.

For your use case, perhaps a `PlayerManager` struct which holds this state and is passed by `&mut` reference to the `new` function is a good idea.

```rust
struct PlayerManager {
    count: usize,
}

impl PlayerManager {
    pub fn add_player(&mut self) {
        self.count += 1;
    }
}

// then...
impl Player {
    pub fn new(manager: &mut PlayerManager) -> Self {
        manager.add_player();
        // TODO: the rest of player construction
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that some kind of Manager struct would be my next recourse. Any chance you could add some example code that illustrates your description of ```PlayerManger```?

Comment: @ANimator120 I've added an example, but it's fairly simplistic (and was initially left out since I didn't think it was needed for this answer).